# Parameter with default value and void with similar signature in C# - how does the compiler know which one to invoke?

Tags: c#, named-parameters

Say I have the following simple two methods:

```
class Question
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no params here");
    }

    public void MyMethod(object o = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("an object here");
    }
}
```

and I invoke one like so:

```
new Question().MyMethod();
```

It results in the no params method's call, writing "no params here".

I understand that I can still call the other, e.g. like

```
new Question().MyMethod(null);
```

but my question is, why doesn't the compiler warn me of a possible ambiguity or force me to be particular? And how does it decide what to call? Simply the one with less parameters?

Comment: It will find the best matching method. In your case the best matching method is `MyMethod()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And how does it decide what to call?

It applies the rules in the [MS specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/) or [ECMA standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) (take your pick). Overloading is *really* complicated - particularly by the time you've got type inference, inheritance, optional parameters, typeless arguments (e.g. `null`, `default`, method groups or lambda expressions) involved.

In this case, it's *relatively* simple. Both methods are *applicable*, and neither is "better" than the other in terms of argument conversions, because there aren't any arguments. There are then tie-break rules - and the one that's important in this case is (ECMA version):

> If neither function member was found to be better, and all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in MQ, then MP is better than MQ. Otherwise, no function member is better.

In other words, it's not ambiguous because one method has no optional parameter without a corresponding argument, and one did.

Note that it's not a matter of "fewer" optional parameters that needed substituting automatically - it's "were there any or not".

As an example of this, consider:

```
class Question
{
    public void MyMethod(int x = 1) {}
    public void MyMethod(int x = 1, int y = 2) {}
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Ambiguous
        new Question().MyMethod();
        // Unambiguous
        new Question().MyMethod(0);
    }        
}
```

The first call (no arguments) is ambiguous because both applicable methods have optional parameters with no corresponding arguments.

The second call (one argument) picks the method with a single parameter, because even though there *is* an optional parameter, it has a corresponding argument - whereas the method with two parameters still has an optional parameter with no corresponding arguments.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) under *Overload Resolution* section:

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a
>   candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>   were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

Answer (score 2):

One has a parameter count that matches exactly, and one has a parameter count that is coalesced to match by inserting a default value at the call site.  The ‘best’ choice for the compiler is clearly the former.

If that were not the case, then how would you call the parameterless method?  You couldn’t, so adding an overload with all optional parameters would break caller code: code that originally called parameterless methods would now call different methods.

As to why it’s not a compiler warning, I can’t tell you the reasoning.  It probably ought to be a warning at the overload’s declaration site, because it’s the API writer’s ‘mistake’.  It’s not the caller’s fault, so it makes little sense to warn at the call site, especially when there’s no ‘fix’ available on the caller’s side.